# What is the most appropriate git server for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, git, gitosis

There is an old [`gitosis` install guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git) at the Community Wiki where one of the opening paragraphs is the following:

> WARNING This guide is written for Gitosis, which has been out of
>   active devolpment since 2008, and no is longer available in later
>   versions of Ubuntu such as Version 12.04. Gitosis seems to have been
>   replaced by Gitolite.

I have no experience with Gitolite and could not find that much information about it on the web. Is this still the recommended Git server for Ubuntu 14.04? Or would you recommend something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) (which used to be based on `gitolite` but now uses [their own `gitlab-shell`](https://about.gitlab.com/2013/02/12/gitlab-without-gitolite/)). The Community Edition is relatively easy to set up on Ubuntu (compared to, say Gitorious), since it is a monolithic Debian package. The software is well-maintained (I think at least a release around every couple of months).

Of course, whether you need the features (web UI, LDAP, etc.) that Gitlab offers is open to debate.

---

I should also point out that [the LTS Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html#git-installing-gitolite) uses Gitolite for setting up a git server ("[the] suggested solution"). This should not be seen as an official endorsement, since the LTS guide also ignores `nginx` in favour of Apache when it comes to web servers.

Comment: Actually, the issue tracker and Wiki per project are quite useful in my case. I'll let other questions pop up before accepting; meanwhile I'll give it a try.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa You should check out the LTS Server guide on Gitolite. (see update)

Comment: @LuísdeSousa, LTS Server guide was my first thought when I saw this question as well. You should definitely keep this guide in mind, as it can answer a decent number of potential questions regarding servers that can be run on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the addendum. Somehow, this guide was not showing up in my web searches.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa which one did you pick, finally?